# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] on localhost using laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and developing an admin panel and trying to integrate Redis 1.0 in Laravel.

When I am trying to set the variable name along with value it prompting an error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

The configurational changes i made it is given below:

- In config/session.php file i replaced file with redis
- ('driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'redis'))
- Under `aliases` array in `config/app.php` file the Redis facade is already included `'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class`
- In `.env` file I replaced `file` with `redis` in `SESSION_DRIVER` variable
- In `database.php` file the config for redis server is given below:

```php
'redis' => [
    'cluster' => true,
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
]
```

Below is my Controller code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Administrator;

use Redis;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {}

    public function myProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $redis = Redis::connection();
        $adminName = $request->route('admin_name');
        if ($redis) {
            echo 'connection done';
        } else {
            echo 'connection not done';
        }
        Redis::set('name', $adminName);
        echo $redis->get('name');
    }
}
```

Please help if anyone have an idea of it.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 65):

I think you are not started the **Redis server** that's why this error is coming.

Just download and install the Redis server 
For download the sever just [redis server install](http://fellowtuts.com/php/install-redis-redis-extension-in-php-on-windows/)

For **windows 64** go here https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases and
=>Download *Redis-x64-3.2.100.msi* file
=>Run it and install it
=>Then open the Redis folder (it will the installed folder) then run "redis-server.exe" file.
=>Now your Redis server is activated
=>You can check this by run "redis-cli.exe" file and type ping it will be pong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Redis from here (https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases)
2. configure config/database.php
3. Check redis with this code block if working normaly

   ```
    try {
    // Create a Redis Instance
    $redis = new \Redis();

    // Try to connect to a redis server
    // In this case within the host machine and the default port of redis
    $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

    // Define some Key
    $redis->set('user', 'sdkcarlos');

    // Obtain value
    $user = $redis->get('user');

    // Should Output: sdkcarlos
    print($user);
   ```

   } catch (Exception $ex) {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
   }